# how can I make my desktop application run from a browser?

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm trying to make installer button like in visual studio website [like there](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IBM.output-colorizer) then you click in install it open vscode in your computer and start to install the extension

how is this possible ?.

[image]

Comment: You need to make a custom [protocol handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-wds-ph-install-registration).

Answer (score 1):

In the case with vscode the website calls a file type already registered in Windows, it could be docx for a Word document, pdf or whatever. Here it is the file type for extensions in vscode. 
If you want the same thing to happen you have to install the application first, register a file type for it with an installer and call a file of that type from the website
Making installers and choosing what type is a bit out of scope for this answer.